# Как записать в переменную cmd вывод команды?

Tags: windows, cmd, variable

Мне нужно поместить в переменную windows cmd вывод команды `git describe --abbrev=0 --tags`.

Я попробовал записать вывод таким образом: `FOR /F "delims=" %i IN ('git describe --abbrev=0 --tags') DO set version=%i`
Но у меня появляется такая ошибка: fatal: `Not a valid object name 0`

Посоветуйте как можно записать результат команды в переменную

Comment: `set "version=%i"`